# How to group by with conditons?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to do a group of items.

For example:

```
Item 1:
name: test1
date: 2018-01-01
column1: column1
column2: column2
column1: column3
column2: column4

Item 2:
name: test1
date: 2018-01-03
column1: column5
column2: column6
column1: column7
column2: column8

Item 3:
name: test2
date: 2018-01-01
column1: column9
column2: column10
column1: column11
column2: column12

Item 4:
name: test3
date: 2018-01-05
column1: column13
column2: column14
column1: column15
column2: column16
```

I want to do a sql, to get the items, grouped by date, but only one per name, with my example:

```
name: test1 
date: 2018-01-03
column1: column5
column2: column6
column1: column7
column2: column8

name: test2
date: 2018-01-01
column1: column9
column2: column10
column1: column11
column2: column12

name: test3
date: 2018-01-05
column1: column13
column2: column14
column1: column15
column2: column16
```

Have you an Idea how to achieve that?
Regards

EDIT: I added some more attributes

Comment: What do you mean "only one by name"? What did you try so far?

Comment: In your example, why 2018-01-03 for  test1 ? do you need the max date? or what else?

Comment: I need all the items, in the example it has only 2 attributes, but it can have multiples ones

Comment: I added some attributes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need such a grouping within a subquery

```
select *
  from tab
 where ( name, "date" ) in
     ( select name, max("date")
         from tab
        group by name 
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with max()

```
select name, max(date) as date
from tablename
group by name
```

Comment: I added some attributes to show how it should work, probably a combinaison with your solution, but I don't see how